# When to dispose dbcontext while using ef second level cache

Tags: entity-framework

People on the inet advise to use "using" clause with the dbcontext..  That means the dbcontext object is getting disposed.. If that's the case, then how this dbcontext will get benefit of having second level caching (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you link to hooks inte EF's provider model an implements cache at a lower layer than the DbContext. You should still use the DbContext as a unit of work and dispose of it as soon as you're done with one set of operations.

Comment: Disposing the dbcontext instance, it means wipe off the lower level cahce (ef provider), am i correct? If yes, then what's the point of writing/implementing the custom ef provider if the cache removed from the memory while the dbcontext getting disposed?

Comment: No, as is explained in the article, disposing the EF context means wiping the upper level cache. The provider level cache is not affected.

Comment: Just wondering if the Dbcompiledmodel can be cached in the seocnd level cache?